# SQL Server copy all rows from one table into another i.e duplicate table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I want to keep a table as history and replace it with an empty one. How can I do this through Management Studio?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Duplicate your table into a table to be archived:

```
SELECT * INTO ArchiveTable FROM MyTable
```

Delete all entries in your table:

```
DELETE * FROM MyTable
```

Comment: This only works if ArchiveTable has not been created yet, otherwise you will get the error "There is already an object named 'ArchiveTable ' in the database.".

Comment: TRUNCATE is a better option than DELETE.

Comment: Note this method copies the column structure and content of the table, but not indexes or primary key information.

Answer (score 29):

Don't have sql server around to test but I think it's just:

```
insert into newtable select * from oldtable;
```

Comment: nice one! but i never trust the order of the fields ;)

Comment: If there was any place where "SELECT *" should be used its in a query like this... It makes a copy of the table without having to know what's in it.

Comment: @Robin - I agree that a * is a good choice here, **IF** the order of fields is the same ;)

Comment: If you do "insert into ... select * from..." then the order is important.  If you use the "select * into ... from ..." it creates the table for you so column order isn't important.  Though of course, using that approach the table must not exist beforehand.

Comment: Well, the question did say duplicate table, so I assumed he meant exact copy.

Answer (score 21):

```
select * into x_history from your_table_here;
truncate table your_table_here;
```

Comment: For more information on why you should use TRUNCATE rather than DELETE see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30325/delete-vs-truncate

Answer (score 15):

Either you can use RAW SQL:

```
INSERT INTO DEST_TABLE (Field1, Field2) 
SELECT Source_Field1, Source_Field2 
FROM SOURCE_TABLE
```

Or use the wizard:

1. Right Click on the Database -> Tasks
   -> Export Data
2. Select the source/target Database
3. Select source/target table and
   fields
4. Copy the data

Then execute:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE SOURCE_TABLE
```

Answer (score 4):

try this **single command to both delete and insert the data**:

```
DELETE MyTable
    OUTPUT DELETED.Col1, DELETED.COl2,...
        INTO MyBackupTable
```

working sample:

```
--set up the tables
DECLARE @MyTable table (col1 int, col2 varchar(5))
DECLARE @MyBackupTable table (col1 int, col2 varchar(5))
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (1,'A')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (2,'B')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (3,'C')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES (4,'D')

--single command that does the delete and inserts
DELETE @MyTable
    OUTPUT DELETED.Col1, DELETED.COl2
        INTO @MyBackupTable

--show both tables final values
select * from @MyTable
select * from @MyBackupTable
```

OUTPUT:

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(4 row(s) affected)
col1        col2
----------- -----

(0 row(s) affected)

col1        col2
----------- -----
1           A
2           B
3           C
4           D

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: This looks more elegant solution. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

```
select * into DestinationDatabase.dbo.[TableName1] from (
Select * from sourceDatabase.dbo.[TableName1])Temp
```