# Stored procedure for copying entire data from one table to another table using SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table `Persons (ID, Name, Address)` and another table `Persons_twin (ID, Name, Address)` in which I want to copy whole rows from `Persons`.

Which is the shortest and best way to copy the data? Below is the code I tried but no execution is happening. Your suggestions are most valuable. Thank you.

```
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Persons_twin](ID, Name, Address)
    VALUES(SELECT ID, Name, Address FROM [dbo].[Persons])
END
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server copy all rows from one table into another i.e duplicate table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691441/sql-server-copy-all-rows-from-one-table-into-another-i-e-duplicate-table)

Comment: VALUES is for inserting a single row of specific values.  So the way you are combining it with a SELECT is invalid.  You use one or the other but not both.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `values` clause and use `select` query directly

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Persons_twin](ID, Name, Address)
SELECT ID, Name, Address FROM [dbo].[Persons]
```

Answer (score 0):

If both tables are the same, you could use this query:

```
INSERT INTO Persons_twin
SELECT * FROM Persons
```

Comment: Dont suggest answer without select column list or insert column list. This could lead to problem in future when there is a change in either of the table

Answer (score 0):

You might even *create* the second table *on-the-fly*. In this case you would not have to bother about the table's structure:

```
SELECT * INTO persons_twin FROM Persons
```

Comment: Is your second syntax valid in `SQL SERVER` ?

Comment: Hi @Prdp, good catch! No [it is not. Find Details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204041.aspx). Will edit my answer...